# Can you sum normal random variables |X| and Y?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've recently learned that you can sum independent normal variable do to this theorem:

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n, n \leq 2$ be independent random variables with $X_i~N(μ_i,σ_i^2)$. Let $S_n=\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n X_i$. Then, $$S_n=N(\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n μ_i, \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n σ_i^2)$$

And as a consequence of this we can work out the expectation value and the variance of this sum by adding the individual expectation values, and summing the squares of each of the variances.

My question is: Is this theorem still valid when summing a half-normal distribution, resulting from a normal random variable that is an absolute value $|X|$ with a standard normal random variable $Y$?

Comment: $|X|+Y$ does not have a normal distribution. You can certainly add any two random variables. Also, you can find the mean and variance of $|X|+Y$ without much difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1,\dots, X_n$ are independent and $f_1,\dots, f_n$ are any functions, then $f_1(X_1),\dots, f_n(X_n)$ are also independent.

In general (whether we have independence or not), expectation is linear. In particular

$$\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[X_i].$$

If $X_1,\dots, X_n$ are pairwise uncorrelated (e.g. independent), then also

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}[X_i].$$

However, in general it's hard to determine the actual distribution of $\sum X_i$.